# Why change the attribute Tooltip content not effective?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm a newest to JavaScript. I have encountered a problem. Please help.

Below is Html code source,

```
<BODY onload="initForm(document.frmTKTNetRemitCC)" onkeydown ="bodyOnKeyDown('onSendValidate(document.frmTKTNetRemitCC)')" scroll="no">
<FORM name="frmTKTNetRemitCC">
<TABLE width="100%" BORDER="0">
<TR><TD width="100%">
<FIELDSET>
    <LEGEND class="TITLE">[LABEL id="TITLE_FOP_FARE"]</LEGEND>
    <TABLE width="100%" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" border="0">
    <TR><TD>
        <TABLE width="100%" border="0">
            <!--Form of Payment-->
            <TR>
                <TD width="1px" rowspan="5"></TD>
                <TD id="LBL_NETREMIT_FORMOFPAYMENT" class="LBL" LabelType="MANDATORY" Tooltip="[LABEL id="TIP_NETREMIT_FORMOFPAYMENT"]" width="1%">[LABEL id="LBL_NETREMIT_FORMOFPAYMENT"]</TD>
                <TD><SELECT class="CBO" id="selfop" name="selfop" Tooltip="[LABEL id="TIP_NETREMIT_FORMOFPAYMENT"]" style="width:95px"></SELECT></TD>
```

JS test code source below:

```
function initForm(p_objForm)
{
    try
    {

       alert(document.getElementById("LBL_NETREMIT_FORMOFPAYMENT").Tooltip);
       document.getElementById("LBL_NETREMIT_FORMOFPAYMENT").setAttribute("Tooltip", "Test Tooltip");
       alert(document.getElementById("LBL_NETREMIT_FORMOFPAYMENT").Tooltip);
```

The result is when alert the Tooltip value, it shows correct with changed.  But the tooltip value display is still remain unchanged.  Is it needed to refresh the page?  Do the tooltip attributes action not same with `document.getElementById("LBL_NETREMIT_FORMOFPAYMENT").innerHTML = ?"?`

------- Update for more detail

CLASS = "LBL"

```
         .LBL { behavior: url([APP id="HTMLROOT"]\AMEX\AX_COMMON\Labels.htc);
    FONT-FAMILY:ARIAL;
    COLOR:BLACK;
    FONT-SIZE:11px;
    FONT-WEIGHT:BOLD;
    }
```

Label.htc

```
      <PUBLIC:COMPONENT>
      <PUBLIC:PROPERTY NAME="LabelType" INTERNALNAME="g_vLabelType"/>
       <PUBLIC:PROPERTY NAME="EncoderName" INTERNALNAME="g_vEncoderName"/>
       <PUBLIC:PROPERTY NAME="FieldEncoderPopulate" INTERNALNAME="g_vFieldEncoderPopulate"/>
       <PUBLIC:PROPERTY NAME="ToolTip" INTERNALNAME="g_vToolTip"/>
       <PUBLIC:PROPERTY NAME="DateFormat" INTERNALNAME="g_vDateFormat"/>
       <PUBLIC:PROPERTY NAME="OnFieldEncoderPopulate" INTERNALNAME="g_vOnFieldEncoderPopulate"/>
      <PUBLIC:PROPERTY NAME="isExternalObj" INTERNALNAME="g_vIsExternalObj"/>
```

g_vTooTip

```
        function DoInit()
        {
          g_vDocument = document;
          g_vStyle = this.style;
          try
           {
              if(g_vLabelType==null)g_vLabelType="NORMAL";

           }
          catch(e)
          {
           }

           if(g_vToolTip!=null) this.title = g_vToolTip;

           this.className = g_vLabelType;


           }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What template are you using?

Comment: Too broad, can you post a question with specific issues?

Comment: Hmm... [Behaviors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531078%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are supported in IE<10 only. They are [Microsoft Extensions to CSS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530723%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and not available in other browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the HTML DOM it isn't `ToolTip`, it's `title`.

Change...

```
alert(document.getElementById("LBL_NETREMIT_FORMOFPAYMENT").Tooltip);
document.getElementById("LBL_NETREMIT_FORMOFPAYMENT").setAttribute("Tooltip", "Test Tooltip");
alert(document.getElementById("LBL_NETREMIT_FORMOFPAYMENT").Tooltip);
```

To...

```
alert(document.getElementById("LBL_NETREMIT_FORMOFPAYMENT").title);
document.getElementById("LBL_NETREMIT_FORMOFPAYMENT").setAttribute("title", "Test Tooltip");
alert(document.getElementById("LBL_NETREMIT_FORMOFPAYMENT").title);
```